# A more efficient method on picking the highest bid from two unequal arrays in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

The following question was given to me:

> Write a script that iterates through two vectors, A and B, which contains bids for a sale of items. It calculates a new vector C that has the highest bid of each element.
>
> for example- A= [1 2 4 6] and B=[5 0 8 10] should produce C=[5 2 8 10]

I worked on this and found two ways to solve this (Two solutions):

**Solution 1**

```
C=zeros(length(A))

For i=1:length(A);

 If A(i)=>B(i)

    C(i)=A(i);

    Else

    C(i)=B(i);

 End

End

disp(C);
```

**Solution 2 (A smarter solution)**

```
C=A

For i=1:length(A)

 If B(i)>A(i)

 C(i)=B(i);

 End

End

disp(C);
```

---

*Then I thought what if A and B were unequal in length*

For example- If A=[1 2 3 4] and B=[4 3 2 4 0 6] were to produce C=[4 3 3 4 0 6]

I thought about this and a solution I could think so far is:

```
If length(A)>length(B)

 m=length(A);

 C=A;

Else

 m=length(B);

 C=B;

End

For i=1:m

 If A(i)=>B(i)

    C(i)=A(i);

    Else

    C(i)=B(i);

 End

End

disp(C);
```

**I am not 100% sure if the above code is perfect, and I would be glad to find new and other efficient methods to solve this problem, please share if you know a better method**

Comment: Just to be sure: by _iterate_ you mean using a loop and not the `max` function right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
C = max([A ; B]);
```

If your vectors can have different lengths, then you can pad the smallest one with `-Inf` elements:

```
C = max([A -Inf(1,numel(B)-numel(A)) ; B -Inf(1,numel(A)-numel(B))]);
```

Best,

Comment: I like how -Inf(1,-2) becomes empty, taking care of my if's!

Comment: `max(A,B)` should be more generally applicable than `max([A;B])`.

Answer (score 1):

If they are the same length, you can easily avoid loops:

```
C = A.*(A>=B) + B.*(B>A)
```

**disclaimer:** I am currently unable to test the code, I am coding from memory and it may contain errors.

For vectors of unequal length you can expand from the above by padding the shorter vector with `0`s (if your elements can only be positive) or `-Inf`

Comment: Your solution does not work when `A(i)==B(i)`, because `C(i)` is then `0`. You should add a `>=` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Following your logic that when the lengths are different you allign both vectors from top you could expand the smallest one and compare in a vectorized manner:

```
% A and B are column vectors
A=[1 2 3 4];
B=[4 3 2 4 0 6];

lenA = length(A);
lenB = length(B);

if lenA>lenB
    C=max([A ;B zeros(1,lenA-lenB)]);
elseif lenA==lenB
    C=max([A;B]);
else
    C=max([B ;A zeros(1,lenB-lenA)]);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case where the vectors are very different lengths, this might be more useful if you are memory constrained.

```
max(max(A),max(B))
```

or simply convert everything to columns first

```
max([A(:);B(:)])
```